# Oracle Virtual Box Shared Folder not mirrored - Windows Host, RHEL VM

Tags: virtual-machine, shared-directory

All,

I'm having a problem with a local VM i've setup recently.  I've setup a RHEL6_64 (6.4) VM on my windows 7 laptop.  I've installed the guest additions correctly.  Via the Virtual Box control console, i've setup shared folders.  I have a pre-established C:\TEMP folder, and I created a C:\VM_STORAGE folder.  I've set these up to automount on the guest vm.  They appear to be mounting correctly:

```
[root@v1dpruitt ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/myvg-rootvol
                       49G  4.6G   42G  11% /
tmpfs                 246M     0  246M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             194M   48M  137M  26% /boot
tmpfs                 246M  4.0K  246M   1% /tmp
storage               466G  140G  327G  30% /media/sf_storage
temp                  466G  140G  327G  30% /media/sf_temp
```

As you can see the current disk is showing my laptop disk size and it's mounted without problems.

The problem is that they don't seem to reflect reality.  Both folders seem to be empty.  Temp is filled with stuff that I move around (it's a working folder) on my host, but the VM shows empty.

To test, i created a file in each of these folders via the VM, and it is persisting:

```
[root@v1dpruitt ~]# echo bob > /storage/bob2
[root@v1dpruitt ~]# ls -l /temp
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4 Dec  6 18:22 bob1
[root@v1dpruitt ~]# ls -l /storage
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4 Dec  6 18:22 bob2
```

But this isn't reflecting in the windows folders.  It's like it created them but there is no connection between the VM and the HOST's folder.. it just mounted from that disk, and created their own folders with no sharing.

This is a problem for me, and outside of how i need this to work.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks,

Denny